# Functioning of volatile variable vs an instance variable

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, volatile

From Java Concurrency in Practice

> Threads share the memory address space of their owning process, all
>   the threads within a process have access to the same variables &
>   allocate objects from the same heap.

Also

> Declaring a variable as volatile means that threads should not cache
>   such a variable or in other words should not trust the values of these
>   variables unless they are directly read from the main memory.

My question is

Say there is a non-volatile instance variable 'a' which is modified by a thread. Won't the modified value of 'a' be updated on the heap. If it is updated on the heap another thread reading that instance variable would automatically read the updated value as threads share the instance variables from the heap. So how is the functioning of a volatile variable different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that a `volatile` variable is **forced** to be flushed from all caches before reading and all reads come from main memory.

An non-`volatile` variable can be cached as many times as is desired in all threads.

Essentially

- Every time you **read** a `volatile` variable *it has the value of the most recent write to it from **any** thread*.
- Every time you **read** a `non-volatile` variable *it has the value of the most recent write to it from **this** thread* and only **may** have the value that other threads have written.

In the specific case that is the most common cause of issues it is quite possible for one thread to write a value to a variable and a second thread **never** sees the new value.

Comment: So do threads while reading writing cache even the instance variables?

Comment: @underdog - they **can** - they don't actually have to and often they don't but the critical point is that you cannot assume either way.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon can you explain "they don't actually have to"?

Comment: @Prakash - A VM writer need not do any cacheing at all but if they do they are not allowed to cache `valatile` variables. Well actually they are but all access to them must flush any cache of them first.

Comment: @Prakash It's because of the underlying hardware architecture.  When multiple processors access a shared memory system, each access takes an order of magnitude longer than when a processor accesses its own private cache.  The processors cooperate to keep the shared memory up-to-date with their caches as time permits or, when the program executes special synchronization instructions (e.g., when accessing a `volatile` field).  The less often a program needs to synchronize caches, the better it will perform.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Completely agree with your response. This is my take on the issue of caching by VM threads: VM implementations need not implement caching for threads as the VM spec does not mandate it; however, since caching is an optimization, most VM implementations would be implementing it.

Comment: The word “cache” should not be taken too literal here. A JVM might compile hot spots into native code using CPU registers for a sequence of calculations and as long as no result has been written back to RAM, the CPU registers act as a “cache”. It might even remove a write operation entirely if it detects that there will be another write operation at a later time which overwrites the value anyway. There might be plenty of other optimizations which might act as a logical “cache” without a hardware cache involved. Declaring a variable as `volatile` imposes certain constraints on these.